# Move External Dependencies to Include Files folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, external-dependencies

I'm using `Visual Studio 2010`.

A sloppy project refactoring left 50% of my project header files listed as external dependencies.

Is there any way to get a list of the "external dependency headers", and move the ones in the project directory to the Include Files folder?

Comment: did you manage to do it anyhow? Have the same problem...

Comment: No automatic solution.  But search the .proj files for lists of includes.  These are XML so you can edit them directly, adding or deleting them from directory listings.